# DAX query to see if there's another row in a table with same id and same date - 1 year

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I've got a table with orders. It contains the following relevant columns:

- OrderId (Key)
- CustomerId
- Date (Hierarchy)

I want to create a new column in the same table: *OrderedSameMonthLastYear* 
The value should be true if there's at least one other order from the same customer the same month one year ago.

I've tried a couple different queries but I don't really know enough DAX to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [EARLIER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx) function to access the previous row context (which is all the rows in the table in this case) and do the comparison between columns, and then use `COUNTROWS()` to count the number of filtered rows.

```
OrderedSameMonthLastYear = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Orders,
            Orders[CustomerId] = EARLIER(Orders[CustomerId]) &&
            Orders[Date].[Year] = EARLIER(Orders[Date].[Year]) - 1 &&
            Orders[Date].[Month] = EARLIER(Orders[Date].[Month])
        )
    ) > 0,
    TRUE,
    FALSE
)
```

The result will be as below:
[image: result]